# Is Full Height HTML screen a good idea?

Tags: html, css, browser

I'm working on a new web site that currently is configured as a full height (that is, 100% available browser window) application.  In terms of layout, it is something like this - http://stevesanderson.github.com/fixed-height-layouts-demo/pane-transitions-tablet.html.

Our web site does nothing with the actual browser window size, like switch browser into full screen mode.  It only uses the available space.

Operationally, this is going to be a semi-internal data entry application.  Almost all pages are data entry forms or summary pages

Personally, I think makes a very nice looking app.  However, some of the other developers are comparing this design with content in scrollable  tags to be the same as iFrames.  And as such should be avoided.

Is there any background / best practices information about designing a web site this way?

Comment: You might also try asking here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm sure this is a fairly unhelpful unsubstantiated opinion--but I like it.

Comment: My only advice is: Don't assume you know the height of the viewport. I see a *lot* of sites that neglect this and force me to zoom out to access content near the bottom (which your average user won't realize). Looks like your implementation doesn't suffer from this major problem.

Comment: In my real app, I make no assumptions about height.  I actually ending up using javascript to make everything fit correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally love sites that choose to do this; I think that it's a great way to use up the available real-estate that you have. My one piece of advice would be to add a `min-width` and a `min-height` to your page so that you don't have to worry about your site breaking if the browser gets too small. This will not only improve the overall user experience, but will also prevent future headaches when trying to get your design to work in obscure dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine, and at first looks more like a 'real' app. The only weirdness with this sort of thing is that on OSX you get a bit of a bouncy effect when you hit the top and bottom because of the rubberbanding on the scroll. If you aren't sure what I mean, grab an iPhone/iPad/Mac and scroll up and down past the top or bottom of the content.

In reality it shouldn't be too hard to enable or disable this feature, so why not start with it, then revaluate once you have gotten going.

Comment: Actual behavior is not an issue at this point.  Only the overall appearance.  I do thank you for letting me know about this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any good practices or background information that I know of on this subject. Just follow the normal rules of thumb, if it looks good, is light and loads well, and it is usable, why not?

Comment: Comments from the other dev's are relating to "we don't think it is a good idea" or "we haven't done it that way".  Actual pages do look really nice though.

Comment: Then there's nothing stopping you. The thing they might be "afraid" of, is that you don't have that traditional, header, content, footer style design, but I see no harm of breaking the box every once in a while. I say go with it.